# Facebook OAuth redirect to IP address

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm developing an intranet-based web app that integrates with Facebook via the Graph API. I am struggling to get OAuth working, and I *think* it's because I'm using an IP address rather than a domain.

I've registered three apps with Facebook, one for dev, one for staging and one for live. They are all configured identically, and for each one I've specified the Site URL in the Developer portal accordingly (I've masked some parts - they're real numbers in Facebook):

- Dev - http://localhost:XXXX/
- Staging - https://192.168.XXX.XXX:XXXX/

The URLs for the OAuth dialog output as you would expect - only the App ID and redirect URL are different on the three systems:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?response_type=code&display=popup&scope=create_event,publish_actions,publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access,manage_pages,read_insights&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:XXXX/path/to/redirect
```

The dev version works fine but staging and live do not - I just get

```
"An error occurred. Please try later".
```

Am I right in thinking that Facebook's OAuth doesn't accept using an IP address rather than a domain for Site URL, and if so is there a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, you cannot use IP addresses. You can use domains or even subdomains, but IP addresses won't work.

Comment: This answer is wrong! This will possible with SSL port forwarding from the "white" IP to the localhost.